# Should I submit an app that only supports Android 6 and 5.1?

Tags: android-6.0-marshmallow, android-7.0-nougat, android-5.1.1-lollipop

On my free time, I started working on an app. Back then Android 6 was recently released and 5.1 was still hot. It seemed logical to use Android 6 as my preferred SDK. Now a days, I barely have any free time and the little that I've had, it's been used up working on this app.

A few days ago, it came to my attention that android started shipping devices with Android 7. So should I submit my app even if 5.1 will soon become obsolete or should I scrap it?

Sorry for my English, it's not my native tongue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should submit it. Just because they're shipping devices with android 7 doesn't mean that there aren't people who still have 5.1 and 6.0. Then you can work on adding compatibility for 7.0 if you have time later

Comment: I thought the same.